# How can I backup wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, xampp

I have xampp and wordpress.
I've accidentally delete some files in the xampp directory, and xampp Apache was not working anyway.

I want to extract my posts and leave dealing with the issue for later.
How do I extract the files/posts?

EDIT: the wordpress and xampp are on my own computer.

Answer (score 0):

Just log into phpMyAdmin (in xampp it should just be http://localhost/phpmyadmin) and export the wordpress database. You could then later import it into a new database and get a new installation of WordPress to access that, or else get the plain text posts out manually.

Comment: I can't access phpmyadmin, and I can't get text manually as Apache isn't working, and I deleted some files so now xampp is not working.

Comment: Is there a folder to move (as a temp solution, and before I mistakenly lose the files)

Comment: Wordpress posts are stored in a database, not in a folder. Ways to access that database include WordPress itself, phpmyadmin, or potentially the command line. But the command line won't give you a straight forward way to export your information. I'm not certain if reinstalling xampp to fix your installation would preserve your data. I would suggest trying to get support from xampp on that.

Comment: I think i came around a command line code that backs up the database, but I don't remember the username (it isn't "root"), is there a way to retrieve the username and the password?

Comment: also, I understand it's a database, but isn't a database on the form of a file?

Answer (score 0):

You can export all your content to a xml file (articles, pictures...) through the admin panel:

https://en.support.wordpress.com/export/

Once your new wordpress configured, you'll just have to import (Wordpress Importer plugin)

Answer (score 0):

WordPress comes with a import/export functionalities already, here is a small animated gif on how to use it.

[image: Animated GIF on how to use the WordPress exporter/importer]

### If your posts have images

it is also recommended to backup your uploads folder that its located in /wp-content/uploads, you can just zip it and save it somewhere.

Whenever you want to import your your posts again you can just unzip the folder inside the same /wp-content directory and replace old files with new ones if asked.

### If you have A LOT of posts

I would also suggest to export the entire database using phpMyAdmin (xampp and also every shared hosting comes with it), [here is a video on how to use phpMyAdmin to export your wp database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BZe41g0FDV0)

Comment: Props on a high quality post, but the OP says he's not on a shared host, hes on XAMPP locally and his installation is broken...